# Take actions when response return using charles

Tags: charles-proxy

I do not know whether it's right to ask this question here. If not suitable, please tell me.

I use [charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) to monitor my Android mobile device's http traffic. It does works and now I want to do something when a reponse returns. For example, I visit www.google.com and the response returns then I want to save response text or do anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I think **there isn't such that option** in CharlesProxy.
The closest option you have, I think, is to save the session and then work on the saved file.

Check out the "**Auto Save...**" option under the "**Tools**" menu, it could help you.